# check existence of twig template in Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

Is there a way in Timber to check to see if a Twig template exists before attempting to render one?

I have seen SO answers for how to accomplish this in Symfony (`$this->get('twig')->getLoader()->exists('AcmeDemoBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig')`), but I need a Timber-specific answer.

If not, I can always use PHP-specific

```php
if ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/templates/template-name.twig' ) { ... }
```

but I thought I'd see if anyone knew of a Timber method to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know much about WP/Timber, but looks like `Timber\Loader` has a [`get_loader` method](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/Loader.php#L140) that should return the Twig loader instance (which you can then call `exists` on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$loader = new Timber\Loader;
if ( $loader->get_loader()->exists( 'template-name.twig' ) ) {
    // file exists
}
```

Thank you @Jeto for the trail.